# C# Html Agility Pack : Remove 2 columns on a table

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, html-agility-pack

I am trying to remove 2 columns on  a table which inside a div which has a attribute "data-group" with value "Revision". The problem is it is removing 2 columns on all the tables or not doing anything.

Below is the code:

```
            string htmlDoc = @"
            <div id='TestCo_1' class='view' data-routingURI='ViewRouter.aspx' data-view='TestCo_1' data-filters='' data-viewVersion='2' data-vmVersion='2.2.0.0'>
              <div id='g1' class='group' data-group='Reddy,HEATHER+M'>
                <div id='gh1' class='gh' style='margin-left:10px;'>
                  <img id='gti1' class='gti' src='Images/closed.png'/>
                  <span id='gt1' class='gt'>Reddy,HEATHER M</span>
                  <a id='ge1' class='groupExport'>
                    <img src='Images/excel.png' title='Excel export Reddy,HEATHER M' class='export'/>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id='gc1' class='gc'/>
                <div id='g2' class='group' data-group='Reddy,HEATHER+M/Data+Check+Status'>
                  <div id='gh2' class='gh' style='margin-left:60px;'>
                    <img id='gti2' class='gti' src='Images/closed.png'/>
                    <span id='gt2' class='gt'>Data Check Status</span>
                    <a id='ge2' class='groupExport'>
                      <img src='Images/excel.png' title='Excel export Data Check Status' class='export'/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id='gc2' class='gc'>
                    <table border='0' class='groupTable' style='margin-left:110px;color:black; background-color:White;'>
                      <thead>
                        <tr style='margin-left:60px;color:blue; background-color:White; '>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='50px'>RK ID</th>
                          <th width='80px'>Plan Year</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Period</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Plan Term Date</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Subscriber Name</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Plan Market</th>
                          <th width='300px'>TestCoTS Review Requested</th>
                          <th width='400px'>Status</th>
                          <th width='60px'>Region</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:311085;id:763;status:Data+Check+Status;'>311085</td>
                        <td>2013</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Year End</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>KEDRION BIOPHARMA INC</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS Data Checks Review Requested</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id='g3' class='group' data-group='Reddy,HEATHER+M/ER+Funding+Status'>
                  <div id='gh3' class='gh' style='margin-left:60px;'>
                    <img id='gti3' class='gti' src='Images/closed.png'/>
                    <span id='gt3' class='gt'>ER Funding Status</span>
                    <a id='ge3' class='groupExport'>
                      <img src='Images/excel.png' title='Excel export ER Funding Status' class='export'/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id='gc3' class='gc'>
                    <table border='0' class='groupTable' style='margin-left:110px;color:black; background-color:White;'>
                      <thead>
                        <tr style='margin-left:60px;color:blue; background-color:White; '>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='50px'>RK ID</th>
                          <th width='80px'>Plan Year</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Period</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Plan Term Date</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Subscriber Name</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Plan Market</th>
                          <th width='300px'>TestCoTS Review Requested</th>
                          <th width='400px'>Status</th>
                          <th width='60px'>Region</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:311077;id:377;status:ER+Funding+Status;'>311077</td>
                        <td>2013</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Year End</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>APPLE ROCK ADVERTISING AND PRO</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS ER Funding Follow Up Requested</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:51212105;id:1506;status:ER+Funding+Status;'>51212105</td>
                        <td>2012</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Year End</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>WORD ACADEMIES, INC.</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS ER Funding Follow Up Requested</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:51212105;id:390;status:ER+Funding+Status;'>51212105</td>
                        <td>2013</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Year End</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>WORD ACADEMIES, INC.</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS ER Funding Follow Up Requested</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id='g4' class='group' data-group='Reddy,HEATHER+M/Match+Verification+Status'>
                  <div id='gh4' class='gh' style='margin-left:60px;'>
                    <img id='gti4' class='gti' src='Images/closed.png'/>
                    <span id='gt4' class='gt'>Match Verification Status</span>
                    <a id='ge4' class='groupExport'>
                      <img src='Images/excel.png' title='Excel export Match Verification Status' class='export'/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id='gc4' class='gc'>
                    <table border='0' class='groupTable' style='margin-left:110px;color:black; background-color:White;'>
                      <thead>
                        <tr style='margin-left:60px;color:blue; background-color:White; '>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='50px'>RK ID</th>
                          <th width='80px'>Plan Year</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Period</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Plan Term Date</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Subscriber Name</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Plan Market</th>
                          <th width='300px'>TestCoTS Review Requested</th>
                          <th width='400px'>Status</th>
                          <th width='60px'>Region</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:311085;id:763;status:Match+Verification+Status;'>311085</td>
                        <td>2013</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Year End</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>KEDRION BIOPHARMA INC</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS Match Verification Review Requested</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id='g5' class='group' data-group='Reddy,HEATHER+M/Plan+Contact+Status'>
                  <div id='gh5' class='gh' style='margin-left:60px;'>
                    <img id='gti5' class='gti' src='Images/closed.png'/>
                    <span id='gt5' class='gt'>Plan Contact Status</span>
                    <a id='ge5' class='groupExport'>
                      <img src='Images/excel.png' title='Excel export Plan Contact Status' class='export'/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id='gc5' class='gc'>
                    <table border='0' class='groupTable' style='margin-left:110px;color:black; background-color:White;'>
                      <thead>
                        <tr style='margin-left:60px;color:blue; background-color:White; '>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='50px'>RK ID</th>
                          <th width='80px'>Plan Year</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Period</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Plan Term Date</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Subscriber Name</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Plan Market</th>
                          <th width='300px'>TestCoTS Review Requested</th>
                          <th width='400px'>Status</th>
                          <th width='60px'>Region</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:311026;id:0;status:Plan+Contact+Status;'>311026</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>INSTITUTE OF FINANCIAL OPERATI</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS Contacts Undeliverable</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:311036;id:0;status:Plan+Contact+Status;'>311036</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>VOTENET SOLUTIONS, INC</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS Contacts Undeliverable</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id='g6' class='group' data-group='Reddy,HEATHER+M/Revision+Status'>
                  <div id='gh6' class='gh' style='margin-left:60px;'>
                    <img id='gti6' class='gti' src='Images/closed.png'/>
                    <span id='gt6' class='gt'>Revision Status</span>
                    <a id='ge6' class='groupExport'>
                      <img src='Images/excel.png' title='Excel export Revision Status' class='export'/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id='gc6' class='gc'>
                    <table border='0' class='groupTable' style='margin-left:110px;color:black; background-color:White;'>
                      <thead>
                        <tr style='margin-left:60px;color:blue; background-color:White; '>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='50px'>RK ID</th>
                          <th width='80px'>Plan Year</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Period</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Plan Term Date</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Subscriber Name</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Plan Market</th>
                          <th width='300px'>TestCoTS Review Requested</th>
                          <th width='400px'>Status</th>
                          <th width='60px'>Region</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:51212105;id:779;status:Revision+Status;'>51212105</td>
                        <td>2013</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Year End</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>WORD ACADEMIES, INC.</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS Additional Data Requested</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id='g7' class='group' data-group='Reddy,HEATHER+M/Testing+Status'>
                  <div id='gh7' class='gh' style='margin-left:60px;'>
                    <img id='gti7' class='gti' src='Images/closed.png'/>
                    <span id='gt7' class='gt'>Testing Status</span>
                    <a id='ge7' class='groupExport'>
                      <img src='Images/excel.png' title='Excel export Testing Status' class='export'/>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div id='gc7' class='gc'>
                    <table border='0' class='groupTable' style='margin-left:110px;color:black; background-color:White;'>
                      <thead>
                        <tr style='margin-left:60px;color:blue; background-color:White; '>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='50px'>RK ID</th>
                          <th width='80px'>Plan Year</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Period</th>
                          <th style='text-align:center;' width='80px'>Plan Term Date</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Subscriber Name</th>
                          <th width='300px'>Plan Market</th>
                          <th width='300px'>TestCoTS Review Requested</th>
                          <th width='400px'>Status</th>
                          <th width='60px'>Region</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:51212105;id:779;status:Testing+Status;'>51212105</td>
                        <td>2013</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Year End</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>WORD ACADEMIES, INC.</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS Testing Review Requested - Failed</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class='dtl'>
                        <td style='text-align:center;' class='link' data-target='ae:311083;id:759;status:Testing+Status;'>311083</td>
                        <td>2013</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Year End</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'/>
                        <td>REDI-GROUP NORTH AMERICA, LLC</td>
                        <td/>
                        <td/>
                        <td style='font-weight:bold;'>TestCoTS Testing Review Requested - Failed</td>
                        <td style='text-align:center;'>Florida</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>";


             HtmlDocument myhtmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                        myhtmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlDoc);
                        var revNodes = myhtmlDoc.DocumentNode
                                      .Descendants("div")
                                      .Where(x => x.Attributes["data-group"] != null && x.Attributes["data-group"].Value.Contains("Revision") == true)
                                      .ToList<HtmlNode>();


        foreach (HtmlNode node in myhtmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div"))
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode revNode in revNodes)
            {
                if (node == revNode)
                {


                    var test = node.SelectNodes("//div[2]//table//tr");
                    //foreach (HtmlNode row in test.Nodes)
                    foreach (HtmlNode row in node.SelectNodes("//div//div[2]//table//tr"))
                    {

                        if (row.SelectSingleNode("td[1]") != null)
                            row.RemoveChild(row.SelectSingleNode("td[1]"));
                        if (row.SelectSingleNode("td[2]") != null)
                            row.RemoveChild(row.SelectSingleNode("td[2]"));
                        if (row.SelectSingleNode("th[1]") != null)
                            row.RemoveChild(row.SelectSingleNode("th[1]"));
                        if (row.SelectSingleNode("th[2]") != null)
                            row.RemoveChild(row.SelectSingleNode("th[2]"));
                        // row.RemoveChild(row.SelectSingleNode("td[8]"));
                    }



                }
            }
        }


        myhtmlDoc.Save(@"D:\REsult.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a context node and you want to select a child `div` or `table` use the path `div` respectively `div/table`. If you start your path with `//div` respectively `//div/table` your selection starts down from the root node of the context node, that is, it searches the whole document. So make sure you use a relative path, if you look for descendants then use `.//div` or `.//div/table` but not `//div/table` as that way you search the whole document of the context node and not the subtree of the context node.